# Rotation animation with custom view

Tags: java, android, animation

I have a custom View, IndicatorView, which is essentially a triangle that orients itself according to a specified angle of a circle with a radius equal to the triangle's length. The angle the triangle points to is frequently updated and I would like to animate between these two positions similar to how a hand on a clock moves. Below is an illustration of my custom view (not drawn proportionally or to scale; drawn according to the Android View coordinate plane):

[image]

In the IndicatorView class, I draw the triangle using a Path object and three PointF objects:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
    path = new Path();
    path.setFillType(Path.FillType.EVEN_ODD);
    //a, b, and c are PointF objects
    path.moveTo(a.x, a.y);
    path.lineTo(b.x, b.y);
    path.lineTo(c.x, c.y);
    path.close();
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
}
```

To calculate the different points, given the angle, I use parametric equations:

```
public void showAngle(){
    //x = centerX + radius * cos(angle)
    //y = centerY + radius * sin(angle)
    //TODO sloppy; tidy up / optimize once finished
    //centerX, centerY, length, and bottomWidth are all values
    //calculated in onSizeChanged
    a = new PointF((float) (centerX + (length * Math.cos(angle))), (float) (centerY + (length * Math.sin(angle))));
    //perpendicular bilateral radius
    double pRadius = bottomWidth / 2;
    //perpendicular angle plus or minus 90 degrees depending on point
    float pAngle = angle - 90;
    pAngle = (pAngle < 0) ? 360 - Math.abs(pAngle) : pAngle;
    pAngle = (pAngle > 360) ? pAngle % 360 : pAngle;
    b = new PointF((float) (centerX + (pRadius * Math.cos(pAngle))), (float) (centerY + (pRadius * Math.sin(pAngle))));
    pAngle = angle + 90;
    pAngle = (pAngle < 0) ? 360 - Math.abs(pAngle) : pAngle;
    pAngle = (pAngle > 360) ? pAngle % 360 : pAngle;
    c = new PointF((float) (centerX + (pRadius * Math.cos(pAngle))), (float) (centerY + pRadius * Math.sin(pAngle)));
    invalidate();
}
```

When I have a new angle, I use an ObjectAnimator to animate between the two angles. I place an AnimatorUpdateListener on the ObjectAnimator and call my showAngle() method in my IndicatorView using the intermediate values specified from the Animator:

```
public void updateAngle(float newAngle){
    //don't animate to an angle if the previous angle is the same
    if(view.getAngle() != newAngle){
        if(anim != null && anim.isRunning()){
            anim.cancel();
        }
        anim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "angle", view.getAngle(), newAngle);
        anim.setDuration(duration);
        anim.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                if(view != null){
                    view.showAngle();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

However, this code produces some strange and unexpected behavior:

- The width size of the triangle changes somewhat drastically. This could be due to casting between different types but it shouldn't be that dramatic.
- The point of the triangle never stops at the specified angle. Instead it just keeps moving in a circle.
- The angle seems to dictate the animations speed rather than where the triangle should stop.
- Sometimes it seems as though there are numerous triangles on the screen. This could be due to the speed, perhaps it's moving very fast.

Obviously, somewhere along the line my calculations must be incorrect, though, I'm struggling to find out where I went wrong. **Question(s):** Is there a more efficient way of getting my custom view to animate rotation to a given angle? If I am approaching this correctly, where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the solution to my problem was rather simple but simple enough to be overlooked. The angle field that was being used for the calculations was in degrees and it just had to be converted to radians in order for it to work with the sin and cos methods.

Change all `PointF` instantiations, for instance:

```
a = new PointF((float) (centerX + (length * Math.cos(angle))), (float) (centerY + (length * Math.sin(angle))));
```

to use the angle in radians:

```
a = new PointF((float) (centerX + (length * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(angle))),
        (float) (centerY + (length * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(angle)))));
```

Also, part of the problem was due to sound constantly being analyzed and the View being updated before the previous animation had time to render a few frames. This led to the IndicatorView hardly moving when the angle was being updated often and when it was not it would quickly move to its destination. This happens because the previous animation is canceled before another animation is set (which is necessary to prevent a delay). This is a tricky problem to fix but one optimization I found was to avoid starting a new animation if the current angle and the previous angle were relatively close to each other.

Hopefully this will be useful for someone stuck with a similar problem. This was all part of a guitar tuner project I was working on and the source can be found on [GitHub](https://github.com/chRyNaN/Android-Guitar-Tuner).